# PHP throws 403 forbidden error when copying client data from gmail and submitting the form

Tags: php, email, gmail

I saving this specific data into my form, but i am getting 403

> Forbidden
>   You don't have permission to access /edit-booking on this server.
>   Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

here is the data of the client.

```html
Day 1 : Katra
  On arrival at Jammu Airport  catch the cab and then proceed to Katra Hotel.  Proceed to Katra. On arrive Check into The hotel. Proceed to local Sightseeing in Katra. Dinner and Overnight stay at the hotel Katra.

Day 2 : Katra Sightseeing
Today Morning After having Breakfast, Proceed to Katra- Vaishodevi Darshan. Dinner & Overnight stay at Katra.                  

Day 3 :  Katra - Amritsar 
Today Morning After having Breakfast, Check out From the Hotel & Proceed to Amritsar . On arrive Check into The hotel. Proceed to local Sightseeing in Amritsar . Dinner and Overnight stay at the hotel Amritsar 

Day 4 : Amritsar Sightseeing
Today Morning After having Breakfast, Proceed to Amritsar - Wagha  Border & visit Golden Temple. Dinner & Overnight stay at Amritsar.      
            


Day 5 : Amritsar Drop 
Today Morning After having Breakfast, Proceed to Amritsar Airport Drop
```

when ever i am trying to save this particular details. i am getting 403 forbidden error. Also changed the source from notepad,wordfile,pdf docx. still given me the same error if i copy this data and save it to my form.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yp4ls.png)

i thaught maybe some special characters are creating this problem so i used preg_replace to eliminate all the specials characters. but still get this error

here is my php code for this.

```html
$b_itinerary = filter_var($_POST['b_itinerary'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$b_itinerary = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\n ]/', '', $b_itinerary);


mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
try {
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE rmt_bookings SET b_itinerary=?");
$stmt->bind_param("ss",$b_itinerary,$b_bkid);
    
$stmt->execute();
if($stmt->affected_rows === 0)
$msg = "Booking Updated Successfully";
$stmt->close();

}
catch (Exception $e) {
  echo "Error : ".$e; //use in development
  error_log($e); //use in production
  echo 'Error:'.$e;
  $msg = "Error".$e;
 
}
```

What is causing the problem.

Here is the Screen Short of 2 Client data, With working and other throwing Error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkZ3V.png)

Comment: That error comes from the server, not from PHP.

Comment: No but, if i try to save other client data, then the form is submitted successfully. the only problem is with this data.

Comment: and also if i remove all the ,.- sign from here then this particular data gets saved successfully. but the other client data also have special char like ',.@& then why only the above data is throwing forbidden error.

Comment: Check the error log on the server.

Comment: No error is logged in the error log file.

Comment: Does the access log show that the PHP script is running? This sounds like a firewall or intrusion protection device detecting something in the parameter that it thinks is a penetration attempt.

Comment: i have tested this code in my localhost XAMPP, it works there. but not on my Server. wait i will share the 2 client data 1 working data and 2nd Throwing error.

Comment: The fact that it only fails on the server is another indication that there's an extra security check enabled there, and this parameter is triggering it.

Comment: This is not a PHP problem, it's something in the server configuration.

Comment: But this are the 2 sources of the data. 1 gets submitted and other throws Error here is the screen shot. https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkZ3V.png

Comment: And also my Namecheap hosting is using Litespeed Not Apache.

Comment: One of the inputs contains something that matches a pattern that the server considers suspicious, the other doesn't. What's so hard to understand about that?

Comment: Do you understand what an Intrusion Protection System is? See https://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/definition/intrusion-prevention

Comment: But i cleared all the whitespaces and empty lines in notepad++ and then saved it, still the same error. How can i check which character is causing intrusion error.

Comment: Divide and conquer. Split the input in half, try each half, see which causes the problem.

Comment: Check, only the Day1 details and description is working properly, Every String Starting From Day 2 is throwing Error. And also i have passed the day 2 description directly to variable and echo it. it worked fine, but the same string when fetch from textbox throws error.

Comment: Like I keep telling you, the server is blocking it, it has nothing to do with PHP.

Comment: I suggest you contact the hosting provider, maybe they can explain what they're doing.

Comment: I have open a ticket to my hosting support team, one more thing i have realized i tested the code, without using post. means i have just written a blank try catch statement and echo only successfull msg on submit, but still that page gives Forbidden error. Now i am not even using $_POST to retrivew the value from textbox.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you could change the script to just `<?php exit;` and you'll still get the error. The error is coming from the server, it has nothing to do with PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had a mod_security problem. your ip is blocked for some reason. as your hosting provider to unblock your ip from there the problem occurred for me.
something in your string must have matched the mod rule, if it was a false positive. the support team will unblock your ip. Do it.